# Load Database from asset to arraylist

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

My SQLite database has around 200~300 lines. My table has two columns: `_id`, `Text`.

I want to load my entire table data into an `ArrayList`, so I can get access to any line by it's `_id` using a function.

My problem is, I'm not sure where to create an `ArrayList` - in my main class or in my DatabaseHelper class as shown in the link below.

https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a pojo class like this:

```
public class Data {

    //private variables
    int _id;
    String _text;

    // Empty constructor
    public Data(){

    }
    // constructor
    public Data(int id, String text){
        this._id = id;
        this._text = text;
    }


    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting text
    public String getText(){
        return this._text;
    }

    // setting text
    public void setText(String text){
        this._text = text;
    }

}
```

Now add following method to the DBHelper class:

```
// Getting All data
 public List<Data> getAllData() {
    List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            data.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            // Adding data to list
            dataList.add(data);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return data list
    return dataList;
}
```

Just call this method from your main class. You'll get all the data in list add the list to ArrayList and populate your ListView. Happy coding :)

Comment: if i add the whole list to arrlist, then after that can i random call it via _id ?, i just wanna show up one random text from the list in dialog's textview

Comment: BTW i have one question, the line : "    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;"
If my table name is android_metada should i write it
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM  + android_metada";

Comment: Use Random() function on ArrayList size, the result will be your (_id).
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM android_metada"; use this query.

Comment: im already do this, now i have another problem, im try to load my database in my listview in dialog (Listview just a test to see if my database loaded) but when im call the function and the method which u give me up there, it gone crash. Would u mind take a look at my project ?, If i cant solve the problem with database before tommorow i think i will change my solution into add string in value, and recall then add it in Array.